# What is the best way to sort an ArrayList based on a already sorted ArrayList?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

For example, I have two arrays:

`arrayA[{name: "apple", value: 1}, {name: "banana", value: 2} , {name: "pear", value: 3}]`
`arrayB[{name: "banana", value: 4}, {name: "apple", value: 5} , {name: "pear", value: 3}]`

The end result should have `arrayB` look like this:

`arrayB[{name: "apple", value: 5}, {name: "banana", value: 4} , {name: "pear", value: 3}]`

The best solution I can think of is a double for loop, one to track my location in `arrayA`, another to track my location in `arrayB`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayB.size(); i++) {
    if (!arrayB.get(i).getName().equals(arrayA.get(i).getName()) {
        Object temp = arrayB.get(i);

        for (int j = i + 1; j < arrayB.size(); j++) {
            if (arrayB.get(j).getName().equals(arrayA.get(i).getName())) {
                arrayB.set(i, arrayB.get(j));
                arrayB.set(j, temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Another example would be if I had these two arrays:

`arrayA[{name: "pear", value: 1}, {name: "apple", value: 2} , {name: "banana", value: 3}]`
`arrayB[{name: "banana", value: 4}, {name: "apple", value: 5} , {name: "pear", value: 3}]`

Then `arrayB` should look like this: (ie. It's save to assume `arrayA` is already sorted.)
`arrayB[{name: "pear", value: 3}, {name: "apple", value: 5} , {name: "banana", value: 4}]`

Comment: I don't understand how the two arrays are related to each other. Of which rules does your order consist?

Comment: I have downvoted this question because it is a zero-effort requirements dump.  If you can [edit] your question to show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, this downvote may be retracted.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the arrays have the same length and the same fruit? Can you have two equal fruit in the same array?

Comment: I added an example to help, it's safe to assume arrayA is always in the correct order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is has `O(n^2)` time complexity - those nested loops will be very slow for large lists.

However, with the aid of a `HashMap`, an `O(n)` solution is possible.

```
Map<String, NameAndValue> map = new HashMap<>();
for (NameAndValue x : arrayB)
    map.put(x.getName(), x);

for (int i = 0; i < arrayA.size(); i++) 
    arrayB.set(i, map.get(arrayA.get(i).getName()));
```

This only works if the lists have the same fruit in different orders and no fruit appears twice.